# Resource Dictionary in Silverlight

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, templates, resourcedictionary

I have been working on trying to make a resource dictionary for weeks now. A Resource Dictionary is where if I would add a button or a check box they would already be formatted. I am having several issues and can"t get anything but the buttons to work for me. I am using Silverlight in Visual Studio. Here is the code for under the App.xaml portion. This part should not have any issues but I am putting it here just in case.

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
         >


<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources_Theme\Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

The code below Where it is commented as checkbox is where the issue should lie. The error I am getting is Unexpected ATTRIBUTE in parse rule PropertyElement ::= . PROPERTYELEMENT Content? ENDTAG.. I am not sure how to fix this and I have tried several things. The button works just fine but the Check Box does not. The code between the check box and the button should be fairly similar so I am not sure where the code is wrong. If someone could help me out the would be great. Also, as a way secondary issue could someone tell me how to get Foreground="White" FontFamily="Arial Bold FontSize="16"    to work with the button.

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
x:Class="DanaTraining.App">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>


<!--Button-->
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle RadiusY="20" RadiusX="20" Stroke="Black">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.828"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF4F1818" Offset="0.491"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--CheckBox-->
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="CheckBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Grid>
                    <CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox.Foreground>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.828"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF4F1818" Offset="0.491"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </CheckBox.Foreground>
                    </CheckBox>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Finally, If anyone could tell me were to find a resource dictionary template for Silverlight that would be great. I would really like

Comment: <Setter.Value" FontSize="20"> is not valid. You cannot add atributes here as <Setter.Value> is already affectly the Value attribute of the Setter object.

Comment: That should not have been there. It must have ended up there from when I was trying to get the Foreground="White" FontFamily="Arial Bold FontSize="16" to work with buttons. Either way, This comment is not answering either of the 2 questions I asked. 1) How to fix check box (buttons already works I don't need that) or 2) How to get Foreground="White" FontFamily="Arial Bold FontSize="16" to work with buttons.

Comment: I think the issue you have here is not how to get Foreground="White" to work with buttons as this as shipped works. You are creating a new template for your button so you will need to handle how properties such as Foreground are handle within the template. Look into template binding and templating controls in WPF. There are loads of resources online to help.

Comment: This is not WPF it is Silverlight please read the question asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-templating the Checkbox which I don't think you need to do as all you are doing is changing the foreground. Instead of setting the template property for the checkbox try setting the foreground directly.

Creating a new template for a control is a very powerful feature of WPF but you are then responcible for wiring in the new template to Commands and Events. I think this may be were you are getting a Checkbox that 'isn't working'.

```
<!--CheckBox-->
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="CheckBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.828"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF4F1818" Offset="0.491"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This did not work. I am Still getting the same error.

Comment: The code avoid is perfectly valid so if you still getting errors it could be done to some other code. If you create a new project and copy and paste sections of code across you should be able to isolate the code that is causing the issue.

Comment: I still got there error. When I originally tried it I created a brand new project with just the check box in it. It gave me the same error.